# Disclosure button - TableRow

Tags: android

I am creating a **Table Layout** in one of my activities. On touch of TableRow I am navigating to another activity. I want that each TableRow should have a disclosure button (like IPhone). It is not difficult adding a button in a TableRow. But I just want to know that is there a default property of TableRow of setting up **Disclosure button**?
Also what do we generally follow? Creating a disclosure button in TableRow or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an [example](http://clayallsopp.posterous.com/building-an-android-app-from-scratch-part-4-l) for disclosure button in table row.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that TableLayout has something you want. It's simply for drawing data row by row. You should check ListView, which is more advanced. But still I haven't seen this feature by default.